# Step By step Authentication and Authorization in Yii2 Framework (Basic Template)

Tags: php, authentication, yii2, authorization, yii2-basic-app

I have searched the web and the only result I am getting is just tons of theories.
I am tired of understanding the concept of authentication and authorization in Yii2 Framework,
I have learned the concept of authentication in yii2 and have gone through the whole documentation of yii2 framework.I need to understand the implementation of auth in yii2 , I am newbie here , can anyone give me a step by step authentication and authorization process in Yii2 framework.
So that my application can just identify the logged-in user and direct them to specific pages.
My Application have four kind of Users:
Admin,Approver,Financier and simple user
I want them to go to their respective pages after successful login.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, made it once and using all as a template, any way you will need login, registration, password reset, email send. That means is not a small topic.

Create a tables just paste it

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auth_assignment` (
  `item_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_name`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auth_item` (
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `rule_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `rule_name` (`rule_name`),
  KEY `idx-auth_item-type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auth_item_child` (
  `parent` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `child` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent`,`child`),
  KEY `child` (`child`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auth_rule` (
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `authKey` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `accessToken` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `money` float NOT NULL,
  `podpis` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `pechat` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;

ALTER TABLE `auth_assignment`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `auth_assignment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_name`) REFERENCES `auth_item` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `auth_item`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `auth_item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_name`) REFERENCES `auth_rule` (`name`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `auth_item_child`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `auth_item_child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `auth_item` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `auth_item_child_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`child`) REFERENCES `auth_item` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**modify your User.php model** Ex: https://bitbucket.org/Asylzat/biznen/src/05007642a67ec5788d8a8e1fcba0020a099f8a6b/models/User.php?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

**And controller** to login and register, i use in one page both. And also look for commented part of actionIndex i use it to create roles.

https://bitbucket.org/Asylzat/biznen/src/05007642a67ec5788d8a8e1fcba0020a099f8a6b/controllers/SiteController.php?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

And to deny access for page, use behaviors

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index', 'update', 'view', 'delete'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

here is admin can access defined pages

For the part of the code use

```
if (isset(Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->getId())['admin'])) echo "do something";
```

And also look for tutorials here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFOIUeU-Y74&index=18&list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF

Hope this helps :)